# Where is the Sign out link?

Tags: support, user-interface

I've found out that there is no "Sign Out" link on the Site. Looked at bottom and top and all over the page. Nor it is present in the user page.

Where is it? It would be useful if present besides the "username" on the top of the page.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Close as dupe in the direction you suggest here completed!

Comment: Cheers @Andrew, I originally did this also because the pictures weren't displaying correctly in the other... they seem to have fixed themselves, which means it matters less (though the other does have an incorrect answer as well).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a Down Pointing Triangle ▼ icon ( blue circle in image ) before the user name, click on it, and you can see the "logout" link.

See the following image,

[image]

Clicking Log Out will clear our cookies and log you out on all devices.

Comment: What's a "reverse" triangle? :-)

Comment: @EmilVikström, see the blue circle,in image, it is reverse trinagle icon.

Comment: I know what triangle you mean, but what is the *reverse* of a triangle? What is the *non-reverse* or *correct alignment* of a triangle? :-)

Comment: Perhaps "upside down pyramid" would be a better description? or downward pointing arrowhead?

Comment: Or a downvote!!!

Answer (score 5):

You can see the logout link, when you move the mouse over the username.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you press on the small triangle next to your username you get a new window. On the top of that window there are 3 links: activity, privileges and log out.

Answer (score 3):

If you put your mouse over your user name then a window appears with log out on the right hand side.

Comment: The CORRECT method needs to be the first thing in the FAQ, since there are umpteen duplicates and so far all the ones I've checked are wrong.  Not because people are liars but because they keep changing the interface.