# Log out of one browser

Tags: support, user-interface, logout

How can I log out of one browser? I don't mind whether it's per site or for all Stack Exchange sites, though having both would be nice.

I don't mean the “[log out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/logout)” link in the [username popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176237/where-is-the-sign-out-link/176238#176238): that would “log you out on all devices”. I only want to log out of one device, I want to stay logged in elsewhere.

I tried the [stackexchange.com ”log out” link](https://stackexchange.com/users/logout), which claims to “clear all local credentials in your browser”. But that only logged me out of https://stackexchange.com/, not out of the Q&A sites. And contrary to the claim it also logged me out of other clients.

So how can I log out of one client while staying logged in in other browsers?

Comment: The obvious answer would be to erase your cookies on that browser. I don't think it's possible using [SE] tools.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Most browsers don't give you such fine control, not without an extension. I had wanted to log out of a Chrome incognito window, where I purposefully keep away from any extension (I normally don't log in, either, but I did to test if some behavior was due to an extension I'd installed).

Comment: @Gilles all modern browsers allow you to do this. In Chrome, click Settings -> Advanced -> Content -> Cookies and Site Data. Granted, it could be much easier...

Comment: @Hiroto sorry, but some (most) of us like to stay logged in on _other_ sites...

Answer (score 2):

See my [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172092/can-we-have-a-log-out-on-this-computer-only-button). This is not currently implemented, but I sure hope that it will be.

Comment: I honestly don't see why this was needed as an "answer". There currently is no answer to this problem, and your feature request should probably be a comment, or even a duplicate closure.